# React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, frontend

using useEffect and `dept []` means that it will just setState once right? it seems that prop is reached to late hence my radio button initial value is not highlighted

```
const [isOnlineSystem, setFutureOnlineSystem] = useState(null);
const [reasonType, setReasonType] = useState('');
const [customReason, setCustomReason] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    setFutureOnlineSystem(props.isFutureOnlineSystem)
}, []);
```

if i user the following code, it will manage to assign a value and when i open my modal form radio button is highlighted however i do not want it to set value on every component update since that prop is reaching once

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setFutureOnlineSystem(props.isFutureOnlineSystem)
    }, [props.isFutureOnlineSystem]);

 <Radio.Group value={isOnlineSystem}
```

Comment: Using an empty deps `[]` will reproduce the same behavior as `componentDidMount()`. However, adding a variable in your deps mean that your `useEffect` will be triggered everytime your variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isOnlineSystem, setFutureOnlineSystem] = useState(null);
```

radio button value can't be set as null. it should be

```
const [isOnlineSystem, setFutureOnlineSystem] = useState('');
```

*using useEffect and dept [] means that it will just setState once right?*

No. dependencies means for that particular deps it will trigger the useEffect.

if you keep that empty. that's mean it will trigger on every state change which is a bad practice.

UPDATE:

```
const isInitial = useRef(true);

 useEffect(() => {
        if(isInitial) {

        setFutureOnlineSystem(props.isFutureOnlineSystem);
        isInitial.current = false;
       }
    }, [props.isFutureOnlineSystem, isInitial]);
```

this will setState only once.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i might have confused you, the idea of mine is to set state once component did mount and set it to isOnlineSystem  then in Radio Button use that boolean in value property to show current chosen one ,  i just want it to trigger it once

Comment: you want to trigger ```useEffect(() => {
        setFutureOnlineSystem(props.isFutureOnlineSystem)
    }, [props.isFutureOnlineSystem]);``` only once? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: i would like to setState only one time not on every component update  or i am understood dependencies array incorrectly